# Convert SQL Query to Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

Please find below a sample of my queries:

```
SELECT SUM(skor) FROM lembar_siswa WHERE  lembar_siswa.kunci_jawaban = lembar_siswa.jawaban AND id_siswa = 143 AND token = 'fvgsJqTw'
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `LembarSiswa` is model name for `lembar_siswa` table.

```
LembarSiswa::whereColumn('kunci_jawaban','jawaban')
           ->where('id_siswa',142)
           ->where('token','fvgsJqTw')
           ->sum('skor');
```

Using Query builder.

```
DB::table('lembar_siswa')->whereColumn('kunci_jawaban','jawaban')
           ->where('id_siswa',142)
           ->where('token','fvgsJqTw')
           ->sum('skor');
```